# SMPT SSL exception origin

Tags: c#, ssl, exception, smtp

I am sending mail using **SMTP SSL** in my **c# code**. While sending mail , iam getting the following exception-

> Server does not support secure connections.

When does this error comes? Does this implies problem on **sender's side** or the **receiver's side.**

SMTP configuration

```
    <add key="EmailUserName" value="mail@gmail.com" />
    <add key="NameToDisplay" value="Admin" />
    <!--Use proper password-->
    <add key="EmailPassword" value="password" />
    <add key="SmtpHostUrl" value="smtp.gmail.com" />
    <add key="SmtpPort" value="25" />
```

SendMail method

```
SmtpClient objSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();
                objSmtpClient.Host = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpHostUrl"];
                objSmtpClient.Port = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SmtpPort"]);
                objSmtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
                objSmtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                objSmtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
                objSmtpClient.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailUserName"],
                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EmailPassword"]);

                objSmtpClient.Send(objMailMessage);
```

Thanks

Comment: It will be that you probably connected on port 25 to an SMTP server.. which doesnt support secure connections on that port - but hey, with no code its like trying to hold smoke in a hurricane

Comment: Thanks! This exception comes for few email IDs and not all. So I wonder how a port issue is coming for a few.

Comment: I didnt think gmail took any emails on port 25 with ssl I thought they all had to be port 465